# A question regarding strong law of large numbers cannot be verified by Borel canteli lemma

Tags: convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Hi my question is this,

let $\mathbb x_1,\ldots,x_n $
be a sequence of Bernouli (p) random variables. Then define

$$\mathbb Y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

Using Strong law of large numbers,  $\mathbb Y_n $ converge to p almost surely. I tried to prove this using borel catelli lemma. But i got it as divergent. 
I have attached my work. Can anyone let me know what i did wrong ?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: First you call the random variables $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ with lower-case $x,$ then you refer to $X_i$ with a capital $X$, and you say $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$ with a lower-case $p,$ then speak of almost sure convergence to capital $P.$ You need to straighten out your orthographic usage.

Comment: Showing that $0\le a_n\le b_n$ and citing the fact that $\sum_n b_n$ diverges to $+\infty$ tells you nothing about whether $\sum_n a_n$ converges. If $\sum_n b_n$ converges then $\sum_n a_n $ converges, and if $\sum_n a_n $ diverges then $\sum_n b_n$ diverges. But if $\sum_n b_n$ diverges, you go back to the drawing board. $\qquad$

Comment: Also, even if it were true that the sum diverged, you wouldn't be able to conclude on the basis of Borel Cantelli that $Y_n$ does not converge to $p.$ The $Y_n$ are not independent.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are the man. I totally forgot it. So can you can give me clue how to start with using borel canteli law ?

Comment: It looks to me like you are doing the right thing. Yes, the LLN proof is a bit harder than this.  Try this:  Use your technique to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P[|Y_{k^2}-p|>\epsilon] < \infty$.  If you can do that then you can conclude (with Borel-Cantelli) the very useful fact $Y_{k^2}\rightarrow p$ with probability 1, which is an important part of the standard proof of LLN.

Comment: @Michael Hi Micheal. Yeah but now i realized that i need to find a larger convergent sequence to prove that. Can you just give me a clue to find it ?

Comment: @DhanuRaja : I don't understand what you mean by "larger convergent sequence."  The proof that $Y_{k^2}\rightarrow p$ essentially repeats the same steps you are already doing, but allows you to make a conclusion at the end.  So the "hint" is to do everything you are already doing, replacing $k$ with $k^2$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yeah i figured it out later. Can you just give me a clue to find a lager convergent sequence ?

Comment: @Michael  According to the comment  of MichaelHardy , i need to find a larger convergent sequence (than the original sequence) to prove that the original series will also converge. But i am having a difficulty of find that.

Comment: I am sure Michael Hardy was not suggesting that you find a "larger convergent sequence" as you interpret.  He was just saying that your current proof is inconclusive. You could make your current proof conclusive in 30 seconds if you replace $k$ with $k^2$ (or, looking at your notation again, $n$ with $n^2$).

Comment: @Michael Hi , yeah i can do that. But i cannot identify the logical reasoning behind that. How can you exactly say (the reason) that i can use $\mathbb \frac{1}{n^2} instead of  frac{1}{n} $.

Comment: Can you clarify your last question? What is the thing you are struggling with?

Comment: @DhanuRaja If you're not catching the subtext here, it's that a naive application of Borel Cantelli doesn't quite cut it. Michael has given a very useful suggestion that you *can* use it to show convergence along the subsequence $Y_{n^2}.$ And then you can show convergence by bounding the gaps... how far can $Y_k$ move away from $Y_{n^2}$ before $Y_{(n+1)^2}$ happens?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Hi ,
This is the suggestion that most of you are telling  in the comments section. isnt it ?

Comment: Yes, this can be used to conclude that $Y_{n^2}\rightarrow p$ with probability 1. And as spaceisdarkgreen mentions, you can place any positive integer $k$ in between two perfect squares, then bound the deviation between $Y_k$ and $Y_{n^2}$.

Comment: @Michael  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Michael If you can , post a link about any example of sub-sequence convergence.This is rather a new topic for me. Thank you once again.

Comment: There are likely much better resources out there, but here is a link that I know since I wrote these notes for my probability class.  Section I.H has an example of independently flipping coins with $P[\mbox{Flip $i$ is heads}] = 1/i$, so the sequence has an infinite number of heads with prob 1, but there are only a finite number of heads over the subsequence $\{1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, ...\}$.  The notes also give a proof of the LLN via this method: http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/with-prob-1.pdf

Comment: @Michael Thank you sir...